# 'Round' gradient on highcharts stacked column to appear as a cylinder

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stacked-chart

is it possible to create this effect in Highcharts? I've tried to define a linear gradient but couldn't work out the stops to get a round cylinder effect similar to this, I also tried to get a 3d column to appear rounded but couldn't find any way to do that:

```
colors = [{
        linearGradient: perShapeGradient,
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgb(247, 111, 111)'],
            [1, 'rgb(220, 54, 54)']
            ]
        }, {
        linearGradient: merge(perShapeGradient),
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgb(120, 202, 248)'],
            [1, 'rgb(46, 150, 208)']
            ]
        }, {
        linearGradient: merge(perShapeGradient),
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgb(136, 219, 5)'],
            [1, 'rgb(112, 180, 5)']
            ]},
```

[image]

Fiddle: [Highcharts column with gradients](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gebje/3/)
Fiddle: [Highcharts 3d Column](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-column-null-values/)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three stops.

Using your example, add a third, intermediate stop. So, instead of:

```
stops: [
  [0, 'rgb(247, 111, 111)'],
  [1, 'rgb(220, 54, 54)']
]
```

Do this:

```
stops: [
  [0, 'rgb(220, 54, 54)'],
  [0.5, 'rgb(247, 111, 111)'],
  [1, 'rgb(220, 54, 54)']
]
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/sjqo3bze/

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Adjust colors to suit, of course.

Or, you know, go nuts! No need to limit it to three stops:

```
stops: [
  [0, 'rgb(128,0,0)'],
  [0.1, 'rgb(204,0,0)'],
  [0.25, 'rgb(245,128,128)'],
  [0.5, 'rgb(230,75,75)'],
  [0.75, 'rgb(220,50,50)'],
  [0.9, 'rgb(230,75,75)'],
  [1, 'rgb(128,0,0)']
]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/sjqo3bze/1/

Output:

[image: screensho2]